# Три или четыре способа извлечь корень

Tags: python

Извлечь корень в Питоне можно тремя способами `x ** 0.5`, `pow(x, 0.5)`, `math.sqrt(x)`. А для целых с целым результатом ещё и `math.isqrt(x)`. Какая между ними разница?

P.S. Например при проверке простоты `n` нужно сделать цикл до корня квадратного из `n`. Так правильно?

```
for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
    ...
```

Речь в первую очередь идёт о корректности (точности вычислений). Производительность на втором месте.

Comment: А в каком смысле "какая разница"? )  Подозреваю, что первые два способа вообще эквивалентны, просто один оформлен оператором, а другой функцией. А так - ну, разные реализации вызываются. Встроенная в язык и библиотечная. У библиотеки `Numpy`, к примеру, тоже свой корень есть, для векторных вычислений. "Вы с какой целью интересуетесь?"

Comment: Измерения "навскидку" показывают, что специализированная функция `math.sqrt` работает быстрее, чем универсальные `**` и `pow`, что логично. Кроме того, `pow` медленнее, чем `**`, возможно, из-за лишнего вызова функции-обёртки. Но так то самому интересно было бы детали послушать )

Comment: @CrazyElf , добавил пример, который послужил причиной вопроса.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy возведение в квадрат у вас в примере происходит один раз до цикла, выбор конкретного способа извлечения корня на скорость выполнения кода в целом в вашем случае практически никак не влияет.

Comment: Четвёртый способ - предалагаю ... экспоненту логарифма, ранее использовался там где не было ф-ции pow но были другие, или нету pow с дробным аргументом. Это экспонента натурального логарифма, тогда степень можно вынести как множитель, т.е. `=exp(степень* ln(число))` на питоне может чуть иначе пишется, но по сути это способ 4.

Answer (score 5):

К сожалению, в `Google Colab` нет функции `math.isqrt`, потому что там `Python 3.7.11`. А насчёт остальных функций можно проверить скорость так (небольшой цикл добавлен, чтобы не было кэширования, а то без цикла `%timeit` ругается, что возможно результаты были закэшированы, хотя они примерно так же соотносятся, я проверял, но лучше принять меры предосторожности):

```
import math
n = 100
%timeit [x ** 0.5 for x in range(n)]
%timeit [pow(x, 0.5) for x in range(n)]
%timeit [math.sqrt(x) for x in range(n)]
```

Вывод:

```
100000 loops, best of 5: 17.7 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 5: 23.9 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 5: 13.2 µs per loop
```

Самая быстрая - специализированная функция `math.sqrt`, что логично. Оператор `**` чуть более медленный, а функция `pow` самая медленная, что, в общем, давно известно. Функцию `pow` имеет смысл применять только с третьим аргументом (остаток по модулю), тогда её использование может быть оправдано.
Также проверим, а выдают ли эти варианты одинаковые результаты. Хотя бы на каком-то списке натуральных чисел:

```
import math
n = 10000
y1 = [x ** 0.5 for x in range(n)]
y2 = [pow(x, 0.5) for x in range(n)]
y3 = [math.sqrt(x) for x in range(n)]
print(y1 == y2 == y3, sum(y1) == sum(y2) == sum(y3))
```

Вывод:

```
True True
```

Ещё можно посмотреть в какой код переводятся эти варианты и убедиться, что код разный:

```
dis.dis('x ** 0.5')

  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (0.5)
              4 BINARY_POWER
              6 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis('pow(x, 0.5)')

  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (pow)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (x)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (0.5)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            2
              8 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis('math.sqrt(x)')

  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (math)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (sqrt)
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (x)
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Если скорость важна, то для извлечения корня видимо нужно использовать специально заточенную под это функцию `math.sqrt`. В общем же случае проще на все случаи жизни использовать оператор `**`. И в случае, когда нас интересует вариант с возведением в степень и дальнейшим взятием остатка по модулю - тут лучше всего функция `pow`.

P.S. Ну и, конечно, если нужно получить сразу много корней, то лучше использовать векторизованный `Numpy` для этого. Использование для задачи range/sqrt/sum векторизированных функций даёт 50-кратное ускорение:

```
import math
import numpy as np

n = 1000000
%timeit sum_py = sum(math.sqrt(x) for x in range(n))
%timeit sum_nu = np.sum(np.sqrt(np.arange(n)))
```

Вывод:

```
10 loops, best of 5: 157 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 5: 3.43 ms per loop
```

Проверка, что результат сошёлся (в данном случае - приблизительно):

```
import math
import numpy as np

n = 1000000
sum_py = sum(math.sqrt(x) for x in range(n))
sum_nu = np.sum(np.sqrt(np.arange(n)))
print(sum_py, abs(sum_py-sum_nu))
```

Вывод:

```
666666166.4588418 1.9550323486328125e-05
```

Answer (score 3):

Если коротко, то разница в реализации. И очевидно в скорости выполнения, входных и выходных параметрах. А вообще-то интересно заглянуть, что там во встроенных функциях.

**pow(x, n)**

```py
 @overload
    def pow(base: int, exp: int, mod: None = ...) -> Any: ...  # returns int or float depending on whether exp is non-negative
    @overload
    def pow(base: int, exp: int, mod: int) -> int: ...
    @overload
    def pow(base: float, exp: float, mod: None = ...) -> float: ...
    @overload
    def pow(base: _SupportsPow2[_E, _T_co], exp: _E) -> _T_co: ...
    @overload
    def pow(base: _SupportsPow3[_E, _M, _T_co], exp: _E, mod: _M) -> _T_co: ...
```

**math.sqrt()**

```py
def sqrt(__x: SupportsFloat) -> float: ...
```

**math.pow()**

```py
def pow(__x: SupportsFloat, __y: SupportsFloat) -> float: ...
```

И немного документации [*math.pow()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=power#power-and-logarithmic-functions). Здесь хотелось бы перевести одно заключение из документации:

> В отличие от встроенного оператора **, math.pow () преобразует оба своих аргумента в тип float. Используйте ** или встроенную функцию pow () для вычисления точных целочисленных степеней.

А так же можно пользоваться и **cmath** модулем, для комплексных чисел и не только. Он возращает комплексное число, но при получении квадратного корня из 4, например, мнимая часть будет равняться `0j`.

```py
def sqrt(__z: _C) -> complex: ...
```

Можно сделать вывод, что под каждую конкретную задачу может быть подобран оптимальная функция для вычислений. Думаю, что тема достаточно обширна и можно исследовать, например, скорости для вычисления в том или ином случае.

Все вышеописанное для версии python 3.х.x.

**upd**

И все таки я решил посмотреть глубже. Не уверен в верности моей попытки, но все же (скажите, где я ошибся). Я решил исследовать две built-in функции: `pow()` и `math.pow()`. Найти их исходный код можно [pow](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c) и [math.pow](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/mathmodule.c).

**Для pow()** были найдены данные строки

```c
/*[clinic input]
pow as builtin_pow
    base: object
    exp: object
    mod: object = None
Equivalent to base**exp with 2 arguments or base**exp % mod with 3 arguments
Some types, such as ints, are able to use a more efficient algorithm when
invoked using the three argument form.
[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
builtin_pow_impl(PyObject *module, PyObject *base, PyObject *exp,
                 PyObject *mod)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=3ca1538221bbf15f input=435dbd48a12efb23]*/
{
    return PyNumber_Power(base, exp, mod);
}
```

Что это может означать? В данной [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html) можно найти, как это работает. А конкретно в документации написано, что используется препроцессор для `CPython` и в данной конструкции *"магическим образом преобразуются в переменные С с типом данных, которые нам нужны"*(вольный перевод.). Функция `PyNumber_Power()` импортируется из DLL библиотеки (могу ошибаться, т.к. нашел только вызов в `python3dll.c`-файле, строка 409, `EXPORT_FUNC(PyNumber_Power)`). Вот в принципе и все.

**Для `math.pow()`** реализация немного интересней:

```c
/*[clinic input]
math.pow
    x: double
    y: double
    /
Return x**y (x to the power of y).
[clinic start generated code]*/

static PyObject *
math_pow_impl(PyObject *module, double x, double y)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=fff93e65abccd6b0 input=c26f1f6075088bfd]*/
{
    double r;
    int odd_y;

    /* deal directly with IEEE specials, to cope with problems on various
       platforms whose semantics don't exactly match C99 */
    r = 0.; /* silence compiler warning */
    if (!Py_IS_FINITE(x) || !Py_IS_FINITE(y)) {
        errno = 0;
        if (Py_IS_NAN(x))
            r = y == 0. ? 1. : x; /* NaN**0 = 1 */
        else if (Py_IS_NAN(y))
            r = x == 1. ? 1. : y; /* 1**NaN = 1 */
        else if (Py_IS_INFINITY(x)) {
            odd_y = Py_IS_FINITE(y) && fmod(fabs(y), 2.0) == 1.0;
            if (y > 0.)
                r = odd_y ? x : fabs(x);
            else if (y == 0.)
                r = 1.;
            else /* y < 0. */
                r = odd_y ? copysign(0., x) : 0.;
        }
        else if (Py_IS_INFINITY(y)) {
            if (fabs(x) == 1.0)
                r = 1.;
            else if (y > 0. && fabs(x) > 1.0)
                r = y;
            else if (y < 0. && fabs(x) < 1.0) {
                r = -y; /* result is +inf */
            }
            else
                r = 0.;
        }
    }
    else {
        /* let libm handle finite**finite */
        errno = 0;
        r = pow(x, y);
        /* a NaN result should arise only from (-ve)**(finite
           non-integer); in this case we want to raise ValueError. */
        if (!Py_IS_FINITE(r)) {
            if (Py_IS_NAN(r)) {
                errno = EDOM;
            }
            /*
               an infinite result here arises either from:
               (A) (+/-0.)**negative (-> divide-by-zero)
               (B) overflow of x**y with x and y finite
            */
            else if (Py_IS_INFINITY(r)) {
                if (x == 0.)
                    errno = EDOM;
                else
                    errno = ERANGE;
            }
        }
    }

    if (errno && is_error(r))
        return NULL;
    else
        return PyFloat_FromDouble(r);
}
```

Можно увидеть не только использования `Argument Clinic`-препроцессора, но и обработку некоторых крайних значений (бесконечность ** бесконечность, например) и обработку ошибок.

Можно копать дальше, не уверен есть ли необходимость. Но инетересно же) можно так же увидеть еще одну интересную реализацию для `long_pow()` [здесь](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/59242431991794064824cf2ab70886367613f29e/Objects/longobject.c)

Comment: А, точно, забыл, что у `pow` есть третий параметр, т.е. она по определению менее специализированная, чем `**`, из-за чего она и более медленная, видимо.

Comment: Ну, на pyi стабы нет особого смысла смотреть - там только типы аргументов и возвращаемых значений прописаны.

Comment: @insolor да, именно эту разницу я и хотел показать. Есть смысл углубляться?

Comment: @Dmitry я не вижу смысла их вообще проводить, потому что сами по себе они ничего не демонстрируют. Лучше словами расписать то что вы хотели сказать.